# I have changed my a:link color with jQuery. Now my a:hover doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-class

Because the colour of the nav was illegible against a particular picture, I want it to change for one particular page. Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id='nav'>
        <ul>
                <li id='navBiog'><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="imageChange(1, 400)" class="navItem">biography</a></li>
                <li id='navConductor'><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="imageChange(2, 400)" class="navItem">conductor</a></li>
                <li id='navOrchestrator'><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="imageChange(3, 400)" class="navItem">orchestrator</a></li>
                <li id='navGallery'><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="imageChange(4, 400)" class="navItem">gallery</a></li>
                <li id='navContact'><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="imageChange(5, 400)" class="navItem">contact</a></li>                    
        </ul>    
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    a.navItem:link,a.navItem:visited{
    font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:right;
    padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#333;
    transition:color 1s;
    -moz-transition:color 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition:color 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition:color 1s; /* Opera */
    }
    #navBiog a.navItem:hover,a:active {color:#cc0099;}
    #navConductor a.navItem:hover,a:active {color:#ff9900;}
    #navOrchestrator a.navItem:hover,a:active {color:#66cc66;}
    #navGallery a.navItem:hover,a.navItem:active {color:#6699ff;}
    #navContact a.navItem:hover,a.navItem:active {color:#FF0;}
```

And jQuery

```
switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0:
                            $('.content').fadeOut(500);
                            $('a.navItem:link').animate({color: "#333"});
                            $('#navBiog a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                              '#navConductor a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                              '#navOrchestrator a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                              '#navGallery a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                              '#navContact a.navItem:hover,a:active').css({'color': ''});

                            break;

                            case 1:
                            $('.content').slideUp(700);
                            $('#biogContent').slideDown(700, function(){
                                $('h1').animate({color: "#cc0099"});
                                $('a.navItem:link').animate({color: "#333"});
                                $('#navBiog a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navConductor a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navOrchestrator a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navGallery a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navContact a.navItem:hover,a:active').css({'color': ''});

                            });
                            break;

                            case 2:
                            $('.content').slideUp(700);
                            $('#condContent').slideDown(700, function(){
                                $('h1').animate({color: "#ff9900"});
                                $('a.navItem:link').animate({color: "#333"});
                                $('#navBiog a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navConductor a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navOrchestrator a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navGallery a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navContact a.navItem:hover,a:active').css({'color': ''});
                            });
                            break;

                            case 3:
                            $('.content').slideUp(700);
                            $('#orchContent').slideDown(700, function(){
                                $('h1').animate({color: "#66cc66"});
                                $('a.navItem:link').animate({color: "#ffffff"});
                                $('#navBiog a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navConductor a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navOrchestrator a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navGallery a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navContact a.navItem:hover,a:active').css({'color': ''});
                            });
                            break;

                            case 4:
                            $('.content').slideUp(700);
                            $('#mediaContent').slideDown(700, function(){
                                $('h1').animate({color: "#6699ff"});
                                $('a.navItem:link').animate({color: "#333"});
                                $('#navBiog a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navConductor a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navOrchestrator a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navGallery a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navContact a.navItem:hover,a:active').css({'color': ''});
                            });
                            break;

                            case 5:
                            $('.content').slideUp(700);
                            $('#contactContent').slideDown(700, function(){
                                $('h1').animate({color: "#ff0"});
                                $('a.navItem:link').animate({color: "#333"});
                                $('#navBiog a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navConductor a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navOrchestrator a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navGallery a.navItem:hover,a:active',
                                  '#navContact a.navItem:hover,a:active').css({'color': ''});
                            });
                            break;

                            default:
                            break;
                        }
```

Sorry for the huge amounts of code, but it's fairly hard to put into words. Anyway the initial color change works, but the hovers don't - obviously this is complicated by the fact that each link in the nav is a different colour on hover...

Thank you so much in advance and sincere apologies if this is an obscenely stupid question/asked a thousand times and I just couldn't find it.

Comment: Why do you repeat an identical chunk of selectors and code for each case? Doesn't that make it insane to debug/keep up-to-date? Aren't they all the same except for the ID of the slideDown???

Comment: It seems to work for me in Chrome, [look](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/Vye5m/2), the color changes on hover... (unless I misunderstood something)

Comment: It's once the 'orchestrator' link has been clicked. the color of the link changes, but the hovers cease to work. In fact, in the jsfiddle the links don't even change color...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <-- UPDATE TUT INCLUDE -->

The following is simply the code from the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/WXYHb/) with full comments on how each piece works so that others who see this may "learn" what is actually going on.

```
$(function() {
    //  Your array of colors to use as "hover over" color of each link
    //  keep in mind, for this to work properly, the number of colors should match the number of links &
    //  their index's should match respectivly (exp. link # 1 will = array[0] as it is the first item in the array)
    var araCss = new Array( "#cc0099", "#ff9900", "#66cc66", "#6699ff", "#FF0" );
    //  Also remember there are several different ways to do this,
    //  for instance you could simply create an attribute in the link named "hoverColor" &
    //  have it equal the link color you want, like: <li hoverColor="#cc0099">...
    //  after that, on the hoverin you could easily get your hover color from $(this).attr("hoverColor")

    //  The following will begin cycling through each list item in the list in order to add the functionality you want
    $("li").each(function(i) {
        //  Here we first add the hoverin/hoverout functions to be called
        $(this).hover(function(eIn) {
            //  For hover in, animate this element to the color desired for this li
            $(this).children("a").animate({ color: araCss[i] });
        },
        function(eOut) {
            //  for hover out, animate this li to the base color desired
            $(this).children("a").animate({ color: "#333" });
        })  //  do not place ; as it will end the line for $(this) and we simply want to continue on
        //  Here we make the call to the link inside each li, as you can see,
        //  jQuery makes it very easy to go from element to the next without need of a recall,
        //  since .hover returns the element is was placed on
        .children("a").click(function(eClk)
        {
            //    Do some work when clicking on link!  //  The following will make the link Blink
            setTimeout(function() { $(this).fadeOut("2000", function(){ $(this).fadeIn("2000") }); }, 10);
            switch(i)    //    0 based off of var i from .each function, thus you can manipulate your content with different link clicks here
            {
                case 0:    //    biography
                    //    content fade out
                    break;
                case 1:    //    conductor
                    //    content slide up
                    break;
                case 2:    //    orchestrator
                    //    content slide down
                    $(this).addClass('color-white').mouseleave(function() { $(this).removeClass("color-white") });
                    break;
                case 3:    //    gallery
                    //    content slide up
                    break;
                case 4:    //    contact
                    //    content slide down
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

> <-- UPDATE -->

Sorry about the long weekend, meant to answer sooner.  Personal life aside, I made you a quick fiddle with prime example of how to simplify what you are trying to do. Try to keep in mind, when using a lib like jQuery, don't work so hard to make stuff do what you want. Someone who helped write the lib already did all of the hard work, all you have to do is tie it together.

Try my fiddle and I think you will see what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/WXYHb/

As you will see, all forms of the code are much more laxed and preform the same purposes of your code, without incident and with jQuery cross-browser support. Enjoy!

> <-- OLD -->
>   Just a bit of advice. Rather than make a huge javascript code to change individual parts, why not make better use of jQuery, JQueryUI and Css styling by writting a css class.
>   In other words, stop trying to do all the hard work jQuery has already done. if you want a few elements to have specific css then write that specific css into a class like:
>       .make-me-black { color: #000 }
>   Then just addClass, or toggleClass, or even switchClass at will to change that elements color on demand

For more information check out the following links:

- (allows to animate the toggling of 2 classes) http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/
- (toggles between 2 classes) http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/
- (Adds a class to a jQuery object) http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
- (Removes a class from a jQuery object) http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

> This doesn't necessarily answer the question directly (i.e. direct example), but I have a meeting to go to, when I get back I'll jsfiddle an example of how to do what you are trying to do in ALOT less lines of code and with much more usability and access

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: One more query - How exactly would I write code that changes the :link color to white on clicking while maintaining the hovers? I only want the color change to happen on clicking the "orchestrator" link, and grey for every other.

Comment: @user1148106: updated fiddle to do somthing like this, not sure exact use. in fiddle I made a .color-white css class then just add it to the orchestrator link when it is clicked using the switch in the link click function

Comment: Thanks - the use is that the image behind the nav changes for each one. The orchestrator image is darker and so making the nav white is necessary for legibility. The only problem I now have is making the hover colors still apply after the nav has changed to white. I have used addClass and removeClass to implement the color change you kindly suggested. But how come the hovers stop working now?

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to set it to remove the class on hover out, if you look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WXYHb/) you should see it in full working order now

Comment: Thanks - Sorry to keep adding to this, but I still don't think you quite get what I want to do. I want every link in the nav to be white after clicking orchestrator but for the multicolor hovers to still have effect.